# How to exclude an SKAction from pause?

Tags: ios, swift, skaction, pause

I have a problem pausing my game. I have a func that automatically spawns new "block" every sec and moves it across the screen. But when I set `paused = true`, everything is paused and I cannot animate my pause label. Is there a way to exclude something from pause? I've searched and nothing works for me. There's the `SKAction` that cannot be paused, unless `paused = true`.

```
//this happens every 1 sec
    block.color = UIColor.blackColor()
            block.position = CGPoint(x: CGFloat(frame.width), y: generateSetting)
            block.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: block.size)
            block.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = BodyType.block
            block.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.ground
            block.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.bobby
            block.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
            block.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
            block.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
            block.physicsBody?.restitution = 0
            block.zPosition = 1
            block.shadowedBitMask = 1

            self.addChild(block)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SKNodes to only pause the layers you want. Create node for the pause layer:

```
let gameLayer = SKNode()
```

Then to add things to the layer:

```
gameLayer.addChild(pausedNode)

addChild(gameLayer)
```

You would also do this for a game layer so you can simply only pause the game layer as that pauses all its children so if you create another layer called `noPauseGameLayer` for example, you wouldn't be pausing whatever is on that layer.

Now, to pause only the layer that you want to pause, do this:

**Swift 3**

```
gameLayer.isPaused = true
```

**Swift 2**

```
gameLayer.paused = true
```

If you have any further questions ask me in the comments

Comment: You are not explaining how the `pauseLayer` should be paused.

Comment: Sorry, I'll add that in

Comment: I'm using Swift 3 and yeah. Is it different in Swift 2? It's a SpriteKit value, so you have to import SpriteKit first

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know the new SpriteKit (in Xcode 8) has a `isPaused` property for `SKNode`. That's great.

Comment: No worries. I'm glad I can put some of my knowledge to use :)

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I think the .isPaused thing in swift 3, is the .paused in  Swift 2. Aaaand it doesn't work :( . I can pause all nodes, but the "blocks" that were generated, before the pause occurs keep moving. The new ones just stop. Have you any others ideas?? Thanks in advance

Comment: Waaaaaait in works perfectly. It wasn't adding children to the same node I pause. Thanks a lot u r the best :D..

Comment: No prob. Glad I could help